# how to implement password complexity while register the user

Tags: password-protection, password-encryption

I am working on a web application. There is a module where we can create user.

I need here password complexity, like the password should be having atleast 1 numeric and a minimum 1 cap word.

how can I do that?

Comment: Programming? What is the question? Because we normally do not teach basics - and that IS a really low level question from the way you formulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Password validation in a form is essential. You can create a password in different ways, it's structure may be simple, reasonable or strong. Here is a simple code that validate various type of password structure through JavaScript codes and regular expression.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  function checkPassword(str)
  {
    // at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter
    // at least six characters that are letters, numbers or the underscore
    var re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}$/;
    return re.test(str);
  }

</script>
```